# How do I get the Blazor Client browser selected language? (So I can use the right decimal separator for calculations on that client browser)

Tags: blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, decimal-point, digit-separator

I try to show and use the right digit separator depending on the clients browser selected language. I'm using a Blazor Server App. I've tried to use the 'Sytem.Globalization' namespace but this only shows the settings of the Server Side browser. Is there a way to get the Client browser language/culure settings?

Comment: Please use Google search before you post. The documentation on [localization for blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is available in the Microsoft Docs.

Comment: I did (of course). And if I Google again after 2 days I end up here looking at my own question. And btw the documentation in that page is not correct. They don't show how to get the cultureinfo (numberformat, dateformat) from the **clients browser selected language**.

Answer (score 2):

You could use javascripts navigator.language property via Interop.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/languages

```
public static class JsInterop  
{  

    public static async Task<string[]> Languages()  
    {  
        return await JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<string[]>("navigatorLanguages");  
    }  
}
```

Add this to your javascript file

```
navigatorLanguages = function () {  
    return Promise.resolve(navigator.languages);  
};
```

This will return an array of string of the users preferred language.

*Note:* If you need to support IE10 or earlier you will need to use the navigator.browserLanguage instead.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found it. One thing is sure: don't use anything like CurrentCulture and or System.Globalization to get the client browser language settings.
You have to get this value BEFORE any Razor Component is loaded so I used the _Host.cshtml file to get the (Mvc.RazorPages.PageBase.) **HttpContext**.
From there I used the "Accept-Language" from the HttpContext.Request.Headers StringValues which in my case returned: "nl,en-GB;q=0.9,en;q=0.8". And that turned out to be correct, nl (Dutch) is the first browser language and English the second. And now you can use CultureInfo: var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"). To get the Decimal separator: char numberDecimalSeparator = Convert.ToChar(culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator). And if you have this you also can get the date format. Etc, etc

Comment: Sorry to say, but this is NOT correct. If you could not get the culture from CultureInfo, you were either running an older version of WASM, or you have configured the middleware on the server side wrong. Since Blazor-WASM 3.2.1 has been released, it added support for internationalization. Simply, anywhere in your code you can use `@CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` or `@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` to get the clients culture.. This works perfectly

Comment: Works perfectly for me in Blazor server Net8. The call to HttpContext now goes in App.Razor instead of_Host.cshtml. Thanks for sharing the solution